# How to get copied text from memory without pasting?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got one requirement which is when the user copy any text the system should get the copied text from the memory into the program without require the user to paste it in a txtbox or similar control. I searched on the internet but I didn't get any information. can somebody suggest or provide some references so that I can follow...????

any help would be highly appreciated...!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a web development standpoint, you can not access the clipboard directly. You will have to create either a Flash or Silverlight hook into the clipboard to get the data.

[Example](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/)

[Another Example](http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=Browser_clipboard_access)

Comment: Neither Flash nor Silverlight can do that.

Comment: I disagree, it's definitely possible.

Comment: That requires a signed Java applet.

Comment: Right, just showing possibilities of how to solve the problem sir.

Comment: @Gabe ur examples are great. I tried the second example seems it works. thanx for ur help

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, you will never be able to do that in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

As it is already pointed out accessing clipboard is either not possible or restricted for security reasons for all components running on a page in a browser (restricted == is unlikely to be enabled by anyone, especially for such "spy on clipboard" purpose).

For standalone application you can either scan clipboard all the time or use clipboard filters.

Native functions are around [SetClipboardViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetClipboardData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Managed: [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard.aspx).